# How to use Generics to implement a REST APIManager in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, urlsession

The APIManager should be able to accept different HTTP body as input based on the API in question and map the response to the desired Model structure for use in ui

This is a sample JSON response which I want to use in my code:

```
 {
    "response_code": 0,
    "data": {
        "app_version_update": "",
        "offers": [
            {
                "title": "Special Scheme1",
                "image": "http://59.145.109.138:11101/Offers/BGL_banner_1080_x_540_1.jpg",
                "r": 1.0,
                "result_count": 5.0
            },
            {
                "title": "test 1",
                "image": "http://59.145.109.138:11101/Offers/Yoho-National-Park2018-10-27_10-10-52-11.jpg",
                "r": 2.0,
                "result_count": 5.0
            },
            {
                "title": "Offer Test 1234444",
                "image": "http://59.145.109.138:11101/Offers/Stanley-Park2018-10-27_10-11-27-44.jpg",
                "r": 3.0,
                "result_count": 5.0
            }
        ],
        "rate": 2000
    },
    "meta": {
        "api_version": 2.0
    }
 }
```

Below is a non-generic function load() which performs a HTTP Post call:

```
func load(urlRequest: URLRequest, withCompletion completion: @escaping (_ response: APIResponse) -> Void) {
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            
            guard error == nil else {
                print("Error fetching data from server\nERROR: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            
            guard let jsonData = data else {
                print("Response Data is empty")
                return
            }
            
            printResponseBody(response: data)
            
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let response = try? decoder.decode(APIResponse.self, from: jsonData)
            
            guard let decodedResponse = response else {
                print("Unable to parse data from response")
                return
            }
            
            print("Decoded Response: ", decodedResponse)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(decodedResponse) }
        }
        
        task.resume()
    }
```

Below is the non-generic APIResponse structure for the above sample API:

```
struct APIResponse: Codable {
    
    let responseCode: Int
    let data: ResultSet
    let meta: Meta

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case responseCode = "response_code"
        case data, meta
    }
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct ResultSet: Codable {
    
    let appVersionUpdate: String
    let offers: [Offer]
    let rate: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case appVersionUpdate = "app_version_update"
        case offers, rate
    }
}

// MARK: - Offer
struct Offer: Codable, Identifiable {

    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let image: String?
    let r, resultCount: Int

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {

        case id, r, title, image, resultCount

        var stringValue: String {
            switch self {
                case .id, .r: return "r"
                case .title: return "title"
                case .image: return "image"
                case .resultCount: return "result_count"
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Meta
struct Meta: Codable {
    
    let apiVersion: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case apiVersion = "api_version"
    }
```

### NOTE:

All the apis share the same structure for response but only the data section changes based on the api.

Can somebody help me with implementing a generic APIManager file which can take different UrlRequest inputs, start a URLSession and decode the obtained JSON response data object to different Model Structures for use in ui code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make the struct generic – by the way you can omit the `CodingKeys` if you specify the `convertFromSnakeCase` key decoding strategy –, if you are not going to encode the data conformance to `Decodable` is sufficient

```
struct APIResponse<D : Decodable>: Decodable {
    
    let responseCode: Int
    let data: D
    let meta: Meta

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case responseCode = "response_code", data, meta
    }
}
```

Then make the function also generic and return all errors in the `Result` type

**Never ignore errors with `try?` in a decoding environment**

```
func load<T : Decodable>(urlRequest: URLRequest, type: T.Type, withCompletion completion: @escaping (Result<APIResponse<T>,Error>) -> Void) {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, _, error in
        if let error = error { completion(.failure(error)); return }
        do {
            let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse<T>.self, from: data!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(.success(response)) }
        } catch {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(.failure(error)) }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Regarding the exclamation mark: `data` is guaranteed to have a value if `error` is `nil`.

If you put the `DispatchQueue` closure into the calling method you can even write

```
func load<T : Decodable>(urlRequest: URLRequest, type: T.Type, withCompletion completion: @escaping (Result<APIResponse<T>,Error>) -> Void) {
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, _, error in
        if let error = error { completion(.failure(error)); return }
        completion( Result{ try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse<T>.self, from: data!)})
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And if you annotate the closure type when calling the method you can even omit the `type` parameter

```
func load<T : Decodable>(urlRequest: URLRequest, completion: @escaping (Result<APIResponse<T>,Error>) -> Void) { ...
```

---

```
load(urlRequest: request) { (result : Result<APIResponse<ResultSet>,Error>) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        switch result {
            case .success(let response): print(response)
            case .failure(let error): print(error)
        }
    }
}
```